# .NET Core project.json commands - Set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

From command line, if I run `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development && dotnet watch run`, my Hosting environment is set to Development.

However, if I add the same line as a command to my project.json file, the hosting environment for the watcher is always production:

```
"commands": {
  "watch": "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development && dotnet watch run"
},
```

Are there any arguments I can pass to dotnet run to make the hosting environment Development? I do need this to work as a command.

Comment: if i remember correctly, the support for commands was removed when moving to dotnet-cli. The replacement for it is the tools section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally figured this out!**

The trick was to right click on the Project, go to Properties then select the Debug tab. Next, under Profile, I selected the name of the command defined in my projects.json: "watch". Once selected, I clicked Add by Environment Variables, and added the Name/Value pair ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and Development.

[image]

What this actually does is is upload the launchSettings.json file under Properties in Solution Explorer. This file could also just be edited manually. The output looks something like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56846/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "LendingTree.CreditCards.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Watcher Development": {
      "commandName": "Watcher Development",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great article that´s help me a lot:
[how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine` package which reads the configuration from command line:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(config["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"])
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

With `dotnet run` you could do like below:

```
dotnet run --ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
```

You should be able to do something similar with `dotnet watch run` too.

Comment: I like what you posted in general, but it unfortunately didn't work for my specific use case. I followed your code example, then updated my command with the --ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development argument. No luck. In fact the arg wasn't passed at all and blew up on the UseEnvironment line.